# Symbolicating stripped binary using symbols from older debug version (inexact graph matching)

Tags: algorithm, graph, reverse-engineering, call-graph

I have binary **A**, which is a debug build with accompanying symbols -- built many years ago. I also have binary **B**, a release build *without* accompanying symbols and is much more recent. I am looking for the most efficient method of matching the symbols from binary **A** to potential candidates in binary **B**.

Given that the debug build is considerably bigger (does more input validation, prints more things to `stderr`, etc.) and that functions invariably change over time, I figure that trying to fingerprint the individual functions will be wasted time.

Therefore, I've decided -- quite out of thin air, so I could be barking up the wrong tree -- that the best way to fingerprint the functions is to create call graphs of both binaries and try to match the vertices (i.e. the functions).

I have already done some preprocessing, so I have the following data structures:

```
# binary A
[[60, 60, 8734], # function 0 is called by functions 60 (twice) and 8734
 [193, 441, 505], # function 1 is called by functions 193, 441 and 505
 [193, 742],
 [23],  
 [21],  
 [21],  
 [26],  
 [26, 1508, 1509, 1573],  
 [24],  
 [25],
 ...] # (~10k functions)

# binary B
[[8999], # function 0 is called by function 8999
 [9016], # function 1 is called by function 9016
 [1126], 
 [7904, 7904, 7913], 
 [182, 336, 396, 396], 
 [9010], 
 [407], 
 [182, 632], 
 [20], 
 [24],
 ...] # (~10k functions)
```

An important note to take away is that there is **no** correspondence between function "0" in binary **A** and function "0" in binary **B**. These are arbitrary IDs I have assigned to each function in each binary.

The next step is that which confounds me. My algorithm-fu is very weak and I cannot think of a clever way to proceed. My (very limited) understanding is that to solve this, I would want to employ some form of [inexact graph matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)). In other words, which set of mappings Ai -> Bi would maximise the similarity of the two call-graphs?

Given that there are additional debugging functions in binary **A** and the obvious fact that programs evolve over time, there is likely no exact match. Ideally, I would want output of the form:

```
[[(37, 0.998), (8432, 0.912), (442, 0.75)], # matching-ness of function "0" in binary A with function "37" in binary B is 0.998, second most likely candidate is function "8432" in binary B with score 0.912, etc.
 [(42, 0.973), (7751, 0.788)], # matching-ness of function "1" in binary A with function "42" in binary B is 0.973, second most likely candidate is function "7751" in binary B with score 0.788, etc.
 [(4579, 0.996), (123, 0.934)], 
 ...] # around ~10k mappings
```

In reality, I would be happy with if I had to make do with only one candidate and no ranking was provided, but one can dream.

Any SO-goers have an idea of where I should start?

Comment: I've started a bounty on this question as I very much appreciated the responses so far, but I'm still stumbling with regards to coming up with an algorithm of my own. Any more direct pointers would be _superb_.

Comment: @Sedate Alien: IMHO your best bet is aligning the executable code -- but rather than writing your own mini-disassembler as I suggested in my answer, you could just use an existing disassembler (e.g. `DUMPBIN /DISASM` on Windows), strip out absolute addresses  in the disassemblies using a Perl script, and run `diff` or similar on the results.

Comment: "Symbolicating"???  I don't think that's a word.  At least not in English.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: What word would you suggest? The term "symbolication" is often used in the OS X ecosystem and I could think of no more appropriate term, but I'm all ears!

Comment: By happenschance, does binary B include any exposed functions or APIs?  Anything exported?  Ideally, does it contain any DLLs or similar?

Comment: @Sedate Alien: that depends on what you are trying to say.  But if you are referring to any process that assign symbols to things, the word is "symbolizing", a perfectly legitimate, long extant word.  And the trademarked illiteracy of corporate products' "ecosystems", is no  excuse for the rest of us with the wherewithal to know better, if we only make the effort.

Comment: @Jake Kurzer: It does contain exported symbols, although not necessarily the same symbols in both binaries.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I suppose "symbolisation" might also work. If a symbol is assigned to concept X, one could say that symbol is "symbolising" (i.e. the present participle, "to be symbolic of" as per Wiktionary). The act itself, however, of assigned said symbol wouldn't also use the present participle.

Comment: Here's the thing:  Exported symbols don't generally change that often, because it's a proper pain in the butt to keep that stuff working if you keep hacking it up and if it's a significant piece of software, chances are good one of your users is abusing those exported symbols somehow.  Particularly, if it calls any DLLs, you might get lucky and find that the version of the DLL hasn't changed, or at least that its exported symbols haven't changed.  This can give you known-contiguous points, which is a pretty big win in inexact matching.

Comment: @Sedate Alien:  However you conjugate "symbolize" you aren't going to come up with "symbolication" (see: http://verbs.woxikon.com/english-verbforms/symbolize.php).  I assume this is also true of "symbolise" for our friends across the pond.   :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly an interesting problem, though I suspect it will be hard to solve.  It appears to be an instance of approximate graph isomorphism on directed graphs.  I didn't find much googling for this, but [here's some software](http://cs.nyu.edu/shasha/papers/agm.html) for solving for undirected general graphs, a more general case which is NP hard.

### Aligning Executable Code

I think the most practical thing you may be able to do is to forget about the runtime information and simply take the executable code sections of each version and use a global alignment algorithm (e.g. [Needleman-Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm), although there do exist much faster but less accurate algorithms) on them that:

1. Treats entire instructions as characters (this will require building a rudimentary disassembler)
2. Disregards address components of instructions entirely
3. Downweights deletions (assuming the "first" file is the debug version, which we expect to be larger)
4. Upweights matches of `CALL` instructions, and possibly other "reliable" sequences of instructions.

Assuming the order that the functions appear in the executables hasn't changed too much (which it won't have, unless the optimised version has used some optimisation that gets the linker to place functions that call each other near each other), this should get you a nice first approximation.

### The Assignment Problem (Bipartite Maximum Matching)

Alternatively, if you can find a way (and my intuition suggests it would need to be an iterative approach, along the lines of how PageRank decides the value of a webpage) to "score" the likelihood that a function `f` in the debug version corresponds to a function `g` in the optimised version, then yes you could use a graph matching technique.  In this case the vertices of the graph would be all functions in both versions, and there would be a weighted edge between every function from the debug version and every function from the optimised version, with the weight determined by your scoring system.

This graph would be bipartite because there will never be an edge between 2 functions in the same version.  That means it is an instance of the [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), for which quite good (and not too complicated) algorithms exist.

However, the missing piece here is the means of deciding the weights for each pairing.  One approximate way of doing this would be to build a vector counting the number of immediate children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren and so on for each function.  You could then compare these vectors using any distance measure you like.  But I expect doing this here will not work well, because we already expect the debug version to contain far more calls to functions than the optimised version.

### Using the Full Call Tree

If you have access to the entire call tree for both, this will give you more information: the sequence of calls made within a function, as well as knowledge of the exact hierarchy of calls.  You might then be able to build a "signature" for each function by doing the using just the latter:

1. Extract the list of distinct functions called by a given function
2. Label the 1st-called function 1, the 2nd-called *distinct* function 2, etc.
3. The signature is just this sequence of function labels in the order that they are called in the function.

Now, [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) can be used to compare 2 signatures.  For more accuracy at the expense of more computation, you could use a variation in which up to k distinct functions in the debug version are allowed to be deleted, for some small k (e.g. k = 3), and the best Levenshtein distance is taken over all such "slimmed down" versions, with a small penalty attached that is proportional to the number of functions deleted.

Comment: I know that the [PATL](http://code.google.com/p/patl/) has at least some facilities re: Levenshtein distances.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it, [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) + [BinDiff](http://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html).

Comment: That looks like it would do the job, but I can't afford it on a poor student's budget. :(

Comment: @Sedate: IDA 5 Pro has a freeware version you can use, else, you might be able to scrape through using the IDA 6 Pro's trial. and the binary differential can be done using an IDAPython script

Comment: @Necrolis: IDA is just within my budget, but my primary difficulty is in the writing of the IDAPython script itself! If that was the easy part, I'd be very happy!

Comment: @Sedate: OpenRCE might have something that can help on the script front, this might also be of help for compairing the binaries: http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/254/PatchDiff_2